# Computing rolling median with a fixed start date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with the following .head():

```
       EC       Date       PE
0  C00529 2000-01-31  21.8799
1  C00529 2000-02-29  24.4603
2  C00529 2000-03-31  17.2053
3  C00529 2000-04-30  17.5083
4  C00529 2000-05-31  18.0368
```

EC is an id for the company. I would like to have a column with the median of 'PE' for each company, but rolling from the minimum date ('Date'). Any idea how to do this in pandas?

Thank you!

Comment: Is date some datetime object ? Or a string indicating some timestamp ,

Comment: Yes, it's a datetime object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `df.expanding` method ([see here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html#pandas.DataFrame.expanding)). Assuming your DataFrame is sorted:

```
df.expanding()['PE'].median()
```

Assuming it is not sorted:

```
df.loc[df['Date'].sort_values().index].expanding()['PE'].median()
```